# Magento 2: how to display "add app to home screen" in devices

Tags: magento2, mobile-device

For mobile users on website I want display notification "add app to home screen" and when customer accept then url to our website save on home screen devices.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just cross over here. The thing you actual looking for is call PWA(Progressive Web Application). You need to have the PWA extension as connector to do it. check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application) out.

You may refer to starbuck & alibaba when accessing to their website via your smartphone.